# Activar y desactivar selects e inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Es posible activar y desactivar un select o los inputs de acuerdo a lo que necesito, es relativamente fácil, aunque no lo consigo. Lo que quiero es simplemente que cuando *pulse o selecccione un select los demás selects se desactiven*.

[image: imagen2]

Por ejemplo al seleccionar un estudiante todos los demas campos se bloqueen, es decir los selects de ciclo academico, carrera y los botones de procesos culminados y en proceso de titulacion.

Código fuente:

```html
<div class="container table table-hover">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h3>Generación de Reportes Varios</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h5 class="center">Filtros para generar reporte</h5>
    <form id="Datos" name="Datos" action="{$fsc->url()}" method="post" class="table">
        
        <label for="ciclo">Estudiante</label>

       

        <div >

           <select name="idestudiante" id="idestudiante" class="form-control col s10">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un estudiante...</option>
                {loop="$fsc->estudiantes"}
                <option value="{$value->idestudiante}">{$value->est_primerapellido} {$value->est_segundoapellido} {$value->est_primernombre} {$value->est_segundonombre}</option>
                {/loop}
            </select>

      
        
        </div>

        <label for="ciclo">Ciclo Académico</label>
        <div class="input-field col s10">
            <select name="ciclo" id="ciclo" class="form-control col s10">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione ciclo académico...</option>
                {loop="$fsc->ciclos"}
                <option value="{$value['id']}">{$value['nomenclatura']}</option>
                {/loop}
            </select>
        </div>
        <label for="carrera">Carrera</label>
        <div class="input-field col s10">
            <select name="idcarrera" id="idcarrera" class="form-control col s10">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione carrera...</option>
                {loop="$fsc->carrera"}
                <option value="{$value->idcarrera}">{$value->car_nombre}</option>
                {/loop}
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <p>
                <label>
                    <i class="medium material-icons">playlist_add_check</i>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="procesos_culminados" id="procesos_culminados" />
                    <span>Procesos Culminados</span>
               </label>
            </p>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <p>
                <label>
                    <i class="medium material-icons">sync_problem</i>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="en_proceso" id="en_proceso"  />
                    <span>Estudiantes en Procesos de titulación</span>
               </label>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="col s12 right">
             <p>
                 <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue generar">
                     <i class="large material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i> 
                     Generar Reporte
                 </a>
             </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfobject/2.1.1/pdfobject.js"></script>

<div id="my-container" class="container"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.generar').on('click', function(){
            if($('#ciclo').val() != null && $('#idcarrera').val() == null){
                alert('Debe seleccionar una carrera para generar el reporte por ciclo'); 
                $('#idcarrera').focus(); 
            }
            else{
                PDFObject.embed('reportes_actions.php?accion=generarReporteEstudiante&idestudiante=' + $('#idestudiante').val() + 
                            '&idciclo=' + $('#ciclo').val() + 
                            '&idcarrera=' + $('#idcarrera').val() + 
                            '&procesos_culminados=' + $('#procesos_culminados').prop('checked') +
                            '&en_proceso=' + $('#en_proceso').prop('checked')
                        + '', "#my-container", {height: "800px;"});
                
            }
        });
        
        $('#idestudiante').on('change', function(){
            $('#ciclo').attr("value",'')
            $('#en_proceso').attr("checked",false)
            $('#procesos_culminados').attr("checked",false)
        }); 
        $('#ciclo').on('change', function(){
            $('#idestudiante').attr("value",'')
        }); 
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Necesitas agregar el evento onchange para cada select y llamar una función para realizar los cambios. ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno puedes lograr lo que mencionas realizando lo siguiente:

```
$('#Datos select').on('change', function(evt){
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // Recuperamos el id del que se cambió
    $('#Datos *').attr("disabled", true); // Con esto deshabilitamos los campos que están dentro del formulario
    $('#' + id).attr("disabled", false); // Con esto habilitamos el combobox que recibio el cambio
});
```

Lo que realizo aqui es que cuando se cambie el valor de cualquier combobox que este dentro del form Datos entonces se bloqueen todos los campos y posteriormente se habilita solo el que cambiaste el valor, dejo el código comentado.

Ahora bien en el caso de que solo quieras bloquear algunos componentes en específico podrias utilizar clases que según veo en los combobox utilizas la clase **form-control** entonces podrias valerte de esa clase ***(O utilizar una clase nueva según requieras y agregarla a todos los componentes que necesitas)*** pero para éste ejemplo utilizaré la clase **form-control** y el código para bloquear los componentes quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#Datos select').on('change', function(evt){
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // Recuperamos el id del que se cambió
    $('.form-control').attr("disabled", true); // Con esto deshabilitamos los campos que utilizan la clase form-control
    $('#' + id).attr("disabled", false); // Con esto habilitamos el combobox que recibio el cambio
});
```

Espero te sirva. ;)

Comment: Si me funciona pero se me bloquean todas las opciones hasta el de generar reportes, como puedo hacerlo para que se me bloque solo el ciclo, el periodo, procesos culminados y en proceso de titulacion.

Comment: Saludos @Xavier, acabo de modificar mi respuesta para la pregunta que me acabas de hacer, espero sea lo que buscas.

Comment: acabo de añadir una clase nueva a los campos para bloquear pero no me realiza ninguna acción

Comment: Si utilizas la clase **form-control** te funciona???. En el caso de que te funcione es porque la nueva clase que añadiste posiblemente se encuentre en un lugar incorrecto

Comment: Tampoco me funciona al utilizar form-control.